# Duplicate Identifier errors

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I got off to  a flying start with VS 2017 and angular 2. Love it. Had everything under control or so  I thought till I put my machine back on and was greeted with 352 errors ie "Duplicate Identifier errors" among others. I discoverd I have the file index.d.ts at two separate locations: Here

```
C:\Users\Julius\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types\node
```

and

```
C:\Users\Julius\Documents\Projects\School\backup\VS2017\ReportBook\ReportBook.Web\node_modules\@types\node
```

I am still wondering how it happened. All was going well from VS 2015 to VS 2017 until now suddenly this errors popup. 
How do I get rid of this errors?

Answer (score 1):

I have been running into this same issue with projects in VS2017.  The same projects did not have these issues in VS2015.

I have been able to get rid of these errors by deleting the @types folder under users, in your case: `C:\Users\Julius\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types`

Comment: Thanks, I have actually done that. Forgot to mention it after I had fixed it